# Using Angular 4 : How i can manage admin and web section within single project

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to create a admin and web section in angular and i am little bit confuse that should i create two separate projects for Admin and Web respectively.
Or i can manage both in single angular 4 Application.

Comment: do you mean an admin page or extra features on the page if an admin logs in?

Comment: If they will use almost completely different components, then making two projects is better for my thought. The projects will be less complicated. When you want to migrate or refactor, it's easier to do it project by project.

Comment: @yogurt thanks for suggestion. I will do the same.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon thanks but I have different functionality for both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage different sections (i.e. Admin and UserFront) in single project by creating different modules. I have a successful experiment [here](https://github.com/ariful19/angularRouting).

[Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/router) has a nice example [here](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/router/eplnkr.html).

Comment: thank you so much for your response i will definitely go through the example.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Hello i am creating the application which has admin panel, student admin panel and front side area like when application is run so 
all panel has diffrent css and js file that's why when i copy student admin panel css into the angular.json file then confilict comes,

Answer (score 0):

I have several projects that contains exactly what you ask. A web project that is split into 2 (sometimes 3) different "sections" depending on the role of the user that logs in. So the roles given to the user when loggin in, defines the sections (components) exposed to the user.

According to my experience and in my situation, it is best to keep the sections in the same project, because all refactoring, optimizing etc. is done in the same project, and if a section is needed to be shared, then this is very easy because its the same project.

To manage the different sections correctly then, I have spent some time creating a solid authentication system for managing roles etc., and a solid routing system that controls the sections (You can use Angular's [canActivate Guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) to control what is accessible).

I must also point out, that all client sided code can never be 100% secure, you must always have server-side validation for sensitive data.

Comment: i have already created Admin panel with CanActive Guard to control logins. Can you please share a sample code to mange different sections in single projects

Comment: I dont have a sample project ready now, but if I have time later, i will do it for you.